# Django get total count and count by unique value in queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, aggregate-functions

I have models `Software` and `Domain` described loosely as:

```
class Software(models.Model)
    id = models.BigInteger(primary_key=True, db_index=True, null=False)
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company')
    domain = models.ForeignKey('Domain')
    type = models.CharField(null=False)
    vendor = models.CharField(null=False)
    name = models.CharField(null=False)

class Domain(models.Model):
    id = models.BigInteger(primary_key=True, db_index=True, null=False)
    type = models.CharField()
    importance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=10, null=False)
```

And I get a `Software` queryset with:

`qs = Software.objects.filter(company=c).order_by('vendor')`

The desired output should have an aggregated `Domain` importance with total count for each unique `Software`, i.e.

```
[
  {
    'type': 'type_1',  \
    'vendor': 'ajwr',   | - unique together
    'name': 'nginx',   /
    'domains': {
      'total_count': 4, 
      'importance_counts': [0.1: 1, 0.5: 2, 0.9: 1] # sum of counts = total_count
    },
  },
  {
    ...
  },
]
```

I feel like the first step here should be to just group the `type, vendor, name` by `Domain` so each `Software` object has a list of `Domains` instead of just one but I'm not sure how to do that. Doing this in memory would make it a lot easier but it seems like it would be a lot slower than using querysets / SQL.

Comment: This looks more like the serializers job (like you said, doing it in python) but to make sure  you avoid doing many db queries you should use `.prefetch_related('domain')`

Comment: I think you're right WRT doing this in memory – although I feel like with a one to many relation on `Domain` _back_ to `Software` it could work in querysets alone

Answer (score 1):

So I would do it like this:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
qs = Software.objects.filter(company=c).prefetch_related(
        'domain'
     ).annotate(
        total_count=Sum('domain__importance')
     ).order_by('vendor')
output = []
for obj in qs:
    domains = obj.domain.all() # using prefetched domains, no db query
    output.append({
        # ...
        'domains': {
            'total_count': obj.total_count,
            'importance_counts': [d.importance for d in domains]
        }
    })
```

And I belive it should be fast enough. Only if finding that it isn't I would try to improve. Remember "Premature optimization is the root of all evil"